# Allow access to a node only if another module has already allowed

Tags: 6, users

I want to change permissions for nodes by `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_grants()`, but I want to allow access to a node only if the *workflow access* module has granted access to it.

something like:

```
if (workflow_access_allowed() && myModule_allowed()) {
  allow()
}
else {
  disallow()
}
```

How do I check wheather workflow_access has already granted access to node? (My module priority in *grants* array in `hook_node_access_records()` is higher than the *workflow access* module.